# Load java premain-class from jar library with ANT

Tags: java, class, ant, jar

Is it possible to load a premain-class from a jar library packed within a jar library? I'have the following setup:

Contets of my library:

```
# jar -tf myLibrary.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
agent/
agent/myAgent.jar
com/
com/package/
com/package/subpackage/
com/package/subpackage/A.class
com/package/subpackage/B.class
com/package/subpackage/C.class
```

Now within my MANIFEST.MF I would like to use something like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.agentpackage.AgentClass
Class-Path: agent/myAgent.jar
```

But unfortunately if I "use" this setup with `-javaagent:myLibrary.jar` it gives me the following error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.agentpackage.AgentClass
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

Is it somehow possible to access a premain-class within a .jar file?

My (truncated) ANT build file for myLibrary.jar:

```
<jar destfile="myLibrary.jar" update="true">
    <zipfileset dir="lib" includes="myAgent.jar" prefix="agent" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="agent/myAgent.jar" />
        <attribute name="Premain-Class" value="com.agentpackage.AgentClass" />      
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

I know I could do the following:

```
<jar destfile="myLibrary.jar" update="true">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="myAgent.jar" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Premain-Class" value="com.agentpackage.AgentClass" />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

But then the contents of myAgent.jar gets inflated within myLibrary.jar and thats not what I want. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't support loading nested jars.

You'll have to use inflated version or place these two jars in the same folder and update classpath correspondingly.

Comment: Hopefully it will support it in the future: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4648386

Comment: Additionally I found this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html `The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes.`